# Magento 1.9.x - How to update customer id in a order

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, database-migration, data-migration, magento-1.4

I am working with Magento CE 1.9.x and my current website is running on Magento CE 1.4.x

After data migration,customer id is missing in every order.

Now i want to update customer ID in order, how can i do that ?

any ideas ?

Comment: Try to import a CSV from your old database which will only have 2 columns. 1) order entity id or increment id and 2) cutomer_id. Read the CSV and add code to update the new database using direct mysql queries or like @jraisanen said. But if you have lot of orders then run direct queries through code. That will be time saving. And for running below code you need entity id. And if you want to use increment id then use Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to update customer ids for each order programmatically,

```
$orderCustomerMapping = array(
    1 => 123,
    2 => 124,
    // ...
    // order_id => customer_id
);

foreach ($orderCustomerMapping as $orderId => $customerId) {
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
    $order->setCustomerId($customerId);
    $order->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jraisanen's answer is correct, but to complete the association, you should also set the customer group id and is guest flag like so:

```
$_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order->getId());         
 $_order->setCustomerId($myCustomerId); //sets the customer id
 $_order->setCustomerIsGuest(0); //sets is guest to false
 $_order->setCustomerGroupId('1');//sets to the "general" customer group
 $_order->save();
```